# swift - How to correctly set up a UITextView

Tags: swift, uitextview

I have a view controller that only has a UITextView in it.  I'm having a problem initializing the UITextView with another one that I pass to the view controller.

Here's the code for the view controller:

(The File class has a string variable: name, and UITextView variable: content)

```
// MARK: Properties
var file: File?
@IBOutlet weak var textViewHome: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    navigationItem.title = file?.name
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    print(file?.content.text)
    print(textViewHome.text)
    textViewHome = file?.content
    print(textViewHome.text)
}
```

The output of those print statements are:

```
Optional("hello")

hello
```

So the textViewHome variable gets set with the correct string but nothing shows up in text view when the app is run.  I've seen a lot of questions similar to this but haven't found one where the UITextView.text variable is correct but nothing actually shows up. Thanks for any advice

Comment: Use `textViewHome.text = file?.content.text ` instead of `textViewHome = file?.content`

Comment: I tried that earlier, but I didn't actually delete the textViewHome = file?.content line.  Once I deleted it it worked.  Moral of the story don't set UITextViews equal to each other.  Thanks @ELKA

Comment: Actually the textView that you set is not in the view hierarchy that why nothing showed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your view hierarchy (what's is showing on the screen) had `textViewHome` because it's a subview of `viewController.view`. When you changed the pointer of textViewHome, the view hierarchy still had the old one because you changes the viewController's pointer and you didn't touch the hierarchy.

**Design Improvement:** It's better to let the File own a string and not UITextView.

```
class File{
    var name: String
    var content: String
}
```

In your viewController, you will have

```
textViewHome.text = file?.content //content is a string
```